# Loop does not work properly

Tags: c#, loops

**I'm not asking to code for me!** Just explain me why infinite loop does not loop=)

```
static void Main()
{
  int i=1;
  while (i>0)
  {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt"))
    {       
      Console.SetOut(writer); 
      Act();            
    }
  }
}


static void Act()
{

    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]; 
    IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id); 

    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8]; 

    ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x002BAAD0, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

    Console.WriteLine("<bytes>" + Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) + "</bytes>");
}
```

`Main` writes to a specific file console's output calling `Act`. The program runs once. Make sense, right?

To make an infinite loop I add:

`int=1
 while (i>0) {}`

...loop. `Act()` action is **INSIDE** the loop, so why does `Main` run infinitely but `Act` still runs once?

Comment: One thing that will terminate your loop early (well, earlier than infinity) is an exception. Put a try/catch immediately inside the loop and use a breakpoint on the catch to discover the issue.

Comment: you dont need `while(i>0)` just `while(true)` would be sufficient for an infinite loop. And as @slugster suggested start using `try..catch` you might learn something new.

Comment: @slugster just made several tries with try/catch and made while(true). There are no mistakes. Act just returns NULL in console. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you restructure your Main() to something similar to this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;


static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt"))
        {
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            while (true)
            {
                Act();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I presume you are copying the example from here: [*C# Read/Write another Process' Memory*](http://www.codingvision.net/security/c-read-write-another-process-memory). You should take note of line 27 in example 2:

> // 0x0046A3B8 is the address where I found the string, replace it with what you found

That warning is there because the location of the buffer you are attempting to read from could potentially change on every single independent run of the application (the article [*Graphical memory layout for notepad process*](http://research32.blogspot.co.nz/2014/10/graphical-memory-layout-for-notepad.html) has some info on using Process Explorer to investigate this).

Also note the line from the Wikipedia article on [*Address space layout randomization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization):

> The locations of the heap, stack, Process Environment Block, and Thread Environment Block are also randomized.

So, the answer to your problem is either:

- follow the example faithfully and determine the correct buffer address before running your app with a hardcoded address
- turn ASLR off for Notepad.exe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this one is incorrect=( Of course I know about that. I open the Notepad, use OllyDbg to get the specific address, paste this address in the code and AFTER that compile it. Do not close it at all. Run the app - OK. Edit string in Notepad, run the app once again - OK. No problems at all. Try to add the loop - no luck at all ='( Tried different ways and combinations, tried recoding the app, adding try&catch - no mistakes during compilation, no mistakes during running, NO STRING IN THE FILE. I simply do not understand what is wrong with the loop...

Comment: Dude hold on a sec! I think you solved my issue with restructuring the Main! Let me check!

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! The loop works now as it should! The minor problem left: your code forces Act to add line, not rewrite it. But I think I will handle it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to close your writer

when u open the file first time, the file change status to locked and the second time the command `new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt")` returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at :

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt"))
{
   Console.SetOut(writer);
   Act();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? I even tried to put complete Act() part instead of just Act() call. Still Null is returned to the console.